# How can I to write Mata value to a txt-file?

Tags: stata

I am using Stata 14 SE. I have fairly long script that utilizes nested loops to generate some Monte Carlo data. At some point a loop may fail and then I want to it to write some results to a txt file so that I know at what point it failed.

For that I use the following code. This part is within several loops of a function that gets called within a few other loops.

```
if(f_iterations == f_it_max - 1) {
    stata(`" display "Price Iteration Failed" "')

    st_local("filenumber_ll",filenumber)
    st_local("j_ll",strofreal(j))

    st_local("filenumber_ll")
    st_local("j_ll")

    stata(`" display "Filenumber=`filenumber_ll'" "')
    stata(`" display "J=`j_ll'" "')

    stata(`" file write myfile4 `" Failure in file `filenumber_ll', market `j_ll' "' _n "')
}
```

And it returns the following output in Stata:

```
Price Iteration Failed
001
2
Filenumber=
J=
```

As you can see Stata sees the value of "filenumber_ll" and "j_ll" but refuses to display it and write to file.

Incidentally I also tried these commands in a standalone code:

```
mata

j=5

filenumber="filenumber"
filenumber

st_local("j_ll",strofreal(j))
st_local("filenumber_ll",filenumber)

stata(`" display "Filenumber=`filenumber_ll'" "')
stata(`" display "J=`j_ll'" "')

stata(`" file open myfile25 using `"!test.txt"', write replace "')
stata(`" file write myfile25 `"Failure in file `filenumber_ll', market `j_ll'"' _n "')
stata(`" file close myfile25 "')

end
```

and then I receive this output:

```
filenumber
Filenumber=filenumber
J=5
```

So it seems to work.

I don't understand why it works in a standalone file, but not within a loop. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Why is this happening?

Bill Gould has written a really useful article related to this, named *[Mata Matters: Macros](http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=pr0040)*. I recommend reading the whole thing, but I'll note that one important piece is that macros are expanded differently in Stata and Mata.

In Stata, the value of a macro in a for-loop can change with each iteration of the loop:

```
forvalues i = 1/100 {
    * The for-loop has only one line of code and one macro,
    * but the macro expands to 100 different values over
    * the course of the loop.
    display `i'
}
```

However, in Mata, a macro is expanded only once — when the Mata function or statement is compiled. If the function is run again, the macro isn't expanded again, even if its value has changed.

In other words, *first* the Mata code is compiled, during which all macros are immediately expanded exactly once, *then* the compiled code is executed. It doesn't matter whether that executed code changes the values of the macros, because the macros will never again be expanded in that Mata code.

In the case of your for-loop, it's as if Mata searches the loop for any macros, replaces them with their values, and only then runs the for-loop. The resulting code is the same as if you'd written the for-loop with only the macros' values to begin with, without any actual macros.

This means that since you have that first `if` wrapped in a for-loop, the macros inside it are immediately expanded, before the loop is executed. Your `if` block includes these lines:

```
st_local("j_ll",strofreal(j))
st_local("filenumber_ll",filenumber)

stata(`" display "Filenumber=`filenumber_ll'" "')
stata(`" display "J=`j_ll'" "')
```

If `` `j_ll' `` and `` `filenumber' `` aren't set when the for-loop is first compiled, they are immediately expanded away. It's exactly the same as if you'd typed:

```
st_local("j_ll",strofreal(j))
st_local("filenumber_ll",filenumber)

stata(`" display "Filenumber=" "')
stata(`" display "J=" "')
```

Only once the macros are expanded and the for-loop compiled is the loop run.

If that doesn't make sense, Bill Gould goes into more depth in the article.

## What does this mean for your code?

You can still access a macro's changing value in Mata, you just can't use the `` `localname' `` syntax to do so. Instead, use `st_local()`. Your last two lines would become:

```
stata(`" display "Filenumber="' + st_local("filenumber_ll") + `"" "')
stata(`" display "J="' + st_local("j_ll") + `"" "')
```

If you need to access a single macro's changing value or the value of a macro set after the Mata code is compiled, use `st_local()`. `` `localname' `` is typically reserved for accessing the unchanging value of a macro set before the Mata code is compiled.

Now, these two lines aren't exactly the world's most readable code. To simplify it, just use the Mata variables that already exist:

```
stata(`" display "Filenumber="' + filenumber + `"" "')
stata(`" display "J="' + strofreal(j) + `"" "')
```

Better still, replace `` stata(`"display ..."') `` with the Mata `display()` function:

```
display("Filenumber=" + filenumber)
display("J=" + strofreal(j))
```

Similarly, use `fopen()` and the other Mata file functions rather than `` stata(`"file ..."') ``. Or instead of using a file, just save the values you need in Mata variables that you display at the end of the code, or use `_error()` to raise an error and stop the code immediately.

## Why did it work interactively?

Your code worked interactively, because the interactive statements aren't wrapped in an if-block, for-loop, or function and are compiled then immediately executed, one after another. They're not compiled all at once and executed as a block.

This means that the earlier lines that change the macros' values affect the later lines. That's not the case when the lines are compiled together.

Comment: Matt, thank you for the very detailed answer. I understand it much better now. Meanwhile I was putting the contents of the loop within another do-file and then call it from within the loop. In that case the macros seem to get updated with every iteration and do what I wanted. But your solution is much more elegant. Thank you again! I spent several days trying to figure it out.